# Php Session renewal when the page is refreshed

Tags: php

I am trying to learn php and I am trying to login with this user;

**When user1 logs in and a new window user2 logs in, when I refresh the user1 page, the user1 information disappears and the user2 information comes.**

There is no such problem with the videos I watch on the internet.
Is there a way to do this without using javascript session storage?

```
 $mail = strip_tags(trim($_POST['mail']));
   $pass= strip_tags(trim($_POST['pass'])) ;



      $control = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE BINARY usermail = :mail and userpass = :pass");      

      $control->execute(array(
           "mail" => $mail,
           "pass" => $pass
        )); 
        if($control->rowCount()){
           $user = $control->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);   

           $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
            header("location:usercontrol");

        }else{
          $error['login'] = "...";
        }
```

Comment: What is the reason I got a vote down?

Comment: A new browser window still shares the same session cookies. Try an Incognito / Private Browsing window or a different browser to see the difference

Comment: User1 and user2 are in the same session? Chrome uses the same session (for a window, incognito gives a second, you cant have more than 2). Why are you stripping tags? You might simplify/break passwords with that logic. You also should hash your passwords if you aren't.

Comment: You could start the script off with `if(!empty($_SESSION['user'])) {exit('You are already logged in');}` (after `session_start`).

Comment: *@phil 
yes, it does not matter when you use it in the hidden window.
*@user3783243 
I did it for testing purposes, I just did not solve this problem.

Comment: What method should I do to open a new user in each new window

Comment: You're going to have to provide more details. This issue doesnt reproduce. Where do you start the session. How do you submit the values? What does https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php return throughout the process, does it change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to check is the is set session is set using the super `$_SESSION` global variable like so

```
       if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
           echo '<script type="text/JavaScript">      
           sessionStorage.clear()</script>'; 
        } else {
           session_start();
           // your code
    }
```

Comment: I do not want to check the presence of the session, the session in the session changes information.
Two tabs open in the browser and I can show users A and B in different tabs in the same browser